# passing handleTextChange into react native elements custom searchbar component

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

I have this code below and I want to pass onchange={handleTextChange} in the SearchBarCustom component. But if I remove onChangeText={setValue} and add in onchange={handleTextChange} in the SearchBarCustom component, I can't type anything in the searchbar. How can I pass in the handleTextChange?

```
const SearchScreen = ({}: StackNavigationProps<Routes, "SearchScreen">) => {  


  
  const SearchBarCustom = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    return <SearchBar value={value} onChangeText={setValue} {...props} />;
  };
    


  return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior='automatic' stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}>
        <View>
        <GoogleAutoComplete apiKey={apiKey} debounce={500} minLength={1} queryTypes={'(cities)'} >
          {({ handleTextChange, locationResults}) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
                <SearchBarCustom
                  onChangeText={handleTextChange} // ???
                  containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#f3f2f8'}}
                  inputContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#e3e3e9', height: 30}}
                  placeholderTextColor = '#96969b'

                  placeholder="Search"
                  platform="ios"
                />
                </View>
              <ScrollView>
                {locationResults.map(el => (
                  <LocationItem
                  { ...el}
                  key={el.id}
                  />
                ))}
              </ScrollView>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}

        </GoogleAutoComplete>
        
        </View>
        
      </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This conforms to what is called in React a controlled component. In the [React documentation for controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) they explain how a local state becomes coupled to what you type in the box.

Once the content of the box is managed in this way you would expect to 'watch' it differently. In particular you might write useEffect code something like this...

```
  const SearchBarCustom = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
       handleTextChange(value)
    }, [value])
    return <SearchBar value={value} onChangeText={setValue} {...props} />;
  };
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect to understand how the function guarded by useEffect only runs when the items in its dependency array change (in this case the array is just `[value]` so it will re-run the effect function only if `value` changes.

Comment: I read the documentation and used the useEffect like you said, but handleTextChange is undefined in the useEffect. How can I fix this?